# date not formatting properly using strtotime

Tags: php

my date is not formatting properly. My date is display as 2016-02-08 2016-02-12 but I want it to display as February 22 February 26, which are the next bloack of days it will display a message. Here is my code.

```
$StartDate = strtotime('2016-01-25');
        $EndDate = strtotime('2016-01-29');
        $CurDate = date("Y-m-d");
        $NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate));
        $PayDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $EndDate));
        while ($CurDate > $NextDate && $CurDate > $PayDate) { 
        $NextDate = date("F j", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
        $PayDate = date("F j", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($PayDate))); }
```

The code works but the problem seems to be with

```
while ($CurDate > $NextDate && $CurDate > $PayDate) {
```

If I change `$CurDate > $PayDate` to `$CurDate < $PayDate` it will display the date as I want but will then push the dates to weeks forward. Thanks fir any help.

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the code above. It would be helpful to see the actual code you're using.

Comment: If you want to calculate with dates, you should not convert them to strings. Use the original timestamps generated by `strtotime` or DateTime objects instead.

Comment: +1 on @jeroen. There are some really neat things you could do with DateInterval, etc. Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: DON'T do `date(strtotime(strtotime))` it's utter waste of cpu cycles, forcing multiple `datestring->timestamp->datestring->timestamp` conversion cycles. `date()` should be usef for final/output formatting, not intermediate steps.

Comment: The full code would be. '$StartDate = strtotime('2016-01-25');
            $EndDate = strtotime('2016-01-29');
            $CurDate = date("Y-m-d");
            $NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate));
            $PayDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $EndDate));
            while ($CurDate > $NextDate && $CurDate > $PayDate) { 
            $NextDate = date("F j", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
            $PayDate = date("F j", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($PayDate))); }'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the OOP approach. This does the same thing as above, but is much cleaner and easier to read, also, it outputs the dates as February 22 - February 26:

```
<?php
//START / END DATES
$startDate = new DateTime('2016-01-25');
$endDate = new DateTime('2016-01-29');

//TODAY 
$curDate = new DateTime('NOW');

//TWO WEEKS FROM START AND END DATE
$nextDate = $startDate->modify('+2 weeks');
$payDate = $endDate->modify('+2 weeks');

echo 'current pay period: '. $nextDate->format('F j').' - ';
echo $payDat->format('F j').'<br>';

while ($curDate->getTimestamp() > $nextDate->getTimestamp() && $curDate->getTimestamp() < $payDate->getTimestamp()) {
    echo 'next pay period: '. $nextDate->modify('+2 weeks')->format('F j').' - ';
    echo $payDate->modify('+2 weeks')->format('F j').'<br>';
}
?>
```

Apologies if this isn't the answer you were looking for, i just used your code and converted it to OOP and outputted the dates you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Emylee, I added it to my site and it looks good, one thing though. How would I display $payDate ? I get a catchable error, cannot turn it into a string or some business. Thanks again.

Comment: You can also format the dates using the format method, check out the dateTime docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php You can use the same thing as date() with 'y-m-d H:i:s' etc. echo $payDate->format('F j')

Comment: I appreciate your help Emylee, last question. will this work to call a div if it falls with the timeframe `<?php if ($curDate->getTimestamp() > $nextDate->getTimestamp() && $curDate->getTimestamp() < $payDate->getTimestamp()) { echo " something.. "; } ?>`

Comment: here's my finished result. `$startDate = new DateTime('2016-01-25');
$endDate = new DateTime('2016-01-29');

//TODAY 
$curDate = new DateTime('NOW');

//TWO WEEKS FROM START AND END DATE
$nextDate = $startDate->modify('+2 weeks');
$payDate = $endDate->modify('+2 weeks');

while ($curDate->getTimestamp() > $nextDate->getTimestamp() && $curDate->getTimestamp() < $payDate->getTimestamp()) {
      $nextDate->modify('+2 weeks');
      $payDate->modify('+2 weeks');
      
}` and to trigger it I have `<?php if ($curDate >= $nextDate && $nextDate <= $payDate) { echo " something " ; } ?>` Good?

Comment: Thanks @Emylee it works great. I have one small hickup. I'm trying to echo something if the dates fall in the right spot. I have `<?php if ( $curDate >= $nextDate && $curDate <= $payDate ) { echo "Pay Week" ; ?>` but it's not working, any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Be sure that when you use the object oriented approach you use the "timestamp()" method, otherwise the > and < opperands wont work like expected. So it should be if ( $curDate->getTimestamp() >= $nextDate->getTimestamp() && $curDate->getTimestamp() <= $payDate->getTimestamp() ) , hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Emylee, that worked. Thanks for all your help.